# this.getAttribute('attribute') returning null even though attributes showing in this.attributes

Tags: javascript, components, web-component

I am working on creating some web components and trying to pull data in from the component attributes. When I console.log(this), it shows the correct element and the attributes associated. Same as when I console.log(this.attributes). However, if I console.log(this.getAttribute('attribute')) or console.log(this.hasAttribute('attribute')) I get back null and false respectively.

Can someone make sense of this? Here is the code I am working with:

index.html

```
<script src="component.js"></script>

<test-component test1="Test-text" test2=""></test-component>
```

component.js

```
const template = document.createElement('template');

template.innerHTML = `...`;

class TestComponent extends HTMLElement {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        const shadow = this.shadowRoot;
        shadow.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        console.log(this); // Shows correct element with attributes
        console.log(this.attributes); // Shows attributes
        console.log(this.getAttribute('test1')); // Returns null
        console.log(this.hasAttribute('test1')); // Returns false

    }
}

window.customElements.define('test-component', TestComponent);
```

Comment: I put your code both in jsfiddle and in codesandbox. Both places it is working and returning proper attribute value and also returns true on hasAttribute. I am on Chrome. Which browser are you on?

Comment: The code works even in Safari.

Comment: Wow...I am mainly working in a current chrome browser, but I also tried this in a current Mozilla browser. Odd. The mozilla browser is a backup, so there's no way I had anything cached previously from this. Thank you for the insight. I will continue testing.

Comment: Chrome, Mozilla, Edge and Opera all give me my original results. Null and false on the last two. Hmm. Could there be some issue from my local environment? Simply running files locally that were created from VS Code...not sure why that would change anything.

Comment: @atiqorin Would you mind throwing this into local files and run from browser? I too am seeing success in JS Fiddle, but not locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only in the `connectedCallback` does your CE exist in DOM.

In the `constructor` it is only pre-processed in memory, you can work with its shadowDOM, but the CE is not in the (main) DOM yet, thus you can not access attributes.

```js
customElements.define('test-component', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
        super()
          .attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
          .innerHTML = `Content in shadowDOM`;
    }
    
    connectedCallback(){
        console.log(this.getAttribute('test1'));
    }
});
```

```html
<test-component test1="A Attribute"></test-component>
```

## BUT! There is a catch

If you **define** the CE **after** it is used in the DOM, the CE will be **in** the DOM and the `constructor` can read its attributes.

You should **never** rely on this behavior

A. Your CE user can load/define in the `<head>`

B. Your CE user can do `let myCE = document.createElement("test-component")`
which runs the `constructor`, but the `connectedCallback` will only run the moment `.appendchild(myCE)` executes

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped clarify what's going on here. I knew there had to be a critical piece that I was missing.